# Word Poker, Who Wins?

Tags: code-golf, string

The input will be two five letter words. They don't actually have to be dictionary words, just any five letters each, all lowercase or all uppercase, your choice. Only A-Z will appear in the input words and they will always be 5 characters in length.

Your program is to score them both as though they were poker hands and output the higher hand. Of course suits won't apply here, only rankings so there's no flushes.

The typical poker ranking system goes: '1 pair', '2 pairs', '3 of a kind', 'straight', 'full house', '4 of a kind', '5 of a kind', and of course there is the possibility the hand (or word in this case) could be worth nothing.

**In the case of ties**, letters closer to A are considered higher, so a pair of As beats a pair of Bs. In some cases both hands might be identical, but in a different order (or not), in that case output either hand or a resorted version of it.

[This external page](http://www.compendia.co.uk/poker_scores.htm) contains information about how to identify the winner and especially addresses ties within the specific rankings, in case you aren't familiar with how to score poker hands.

**In the case of straights**: the letters must be adjacent in the alphabet and are not allowed to wrap around. So 'defgh' in any order is a straight, 'xyzab' is not.

Examples of how to score a single hand:

```
word   | scored as
---------------------
ccccc  | 5 of a kind     <-- highest ranking
woooo  | 4 of a kind
opopo  | full house
vurst  | straight
vovvu  | 3 of a kind
ppoww  | 2 pairs
upper  | 1 pair
kjsdf  | high card only (in this case D) <-- lowest ranking
```

So the program will actually produce results like this:

```
input        |  output
-----------------------
voviu,kjsdf  |  voviu     because a pair beats nothing 
opoqo,upper  |  opoqo     because 3 of a kind beats a pair
woooo,ggegg  |  ggegg     because 4 Gs beats 4 Os
queue,hopup  |  queue     because 2 pairs beats 1 pair
lodpl,ddkop  |  ddkop     because pair DD beats pair LL
huhyg,hijht  |  huhyg     both have pair HH, but G beats I
ddffh,ccyyz  |  ccyyz     both have 2 pairs, but CC(yyz) beats DD(ffh)
okaok,nkunk  |  nkunk     KK ties with KK, but NN beats OO
abcdf,bcdef  |  bcdef     because it is a straight
qtery,retyq  |  qtery     identical! so doesnt matter
abedc,vyxwz  |  abedc     because it is a "higher" straight
hhhij,hijkl  |  hijkl     because straight beats 3 of a kind
aaabb,zzzzz  |  zzzzz     because nothing beats 5 of a kind
```

The order of the letters in both the input and output are irrelevant, so the order in your output can be different than the input, but the same inventory of letters needs to be present.

The output must contain exactly five letters -- no more, no less.

The usual codegolf rules apply. Shortest code wins.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (<s>224</s> <s>218</s> 213 bytes)

```
s=>t=>(v=s=>(o={},l=n=0,z=3.5,[...s].sort().map(c=>(n+=o[c]=-~o[c],z*=!l|l+1==(l=c.charCodeAt()))),[n+z,Object.keys(o).sort((a,b)=>o[b]-o[a]||(o[b]>o[a]?1:-1))]),w=v(s),x=v(t),w[0]>x[0]||w[0]==x[0]&&w[1]<x[1]?s:t)
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
s=>t=>(
  v=s=>(
    o={},
    l=n=0,
    z=3.5,
    [...s].sort().map(c=>(
      n+=o[c]=-~o[c],
      z*=!l|l+1==(l=c.charCodeAt())
    )),
    [n+z,Object.keys(o).sort((a,b)=>o[b]-o[a]||(o[b]>o[a]?1:-1))]
  ),
  w=v(s),x=v(t),
  w[0]>x[0] || w[0]==x[0] && w[1]<x[1] ? s : t
)
```

After `map()` runs, `n + z` determines the ranking of a hand:

[image]

(You can understand why I initialized `z` to 3.5.)

In case of a tie, `Object.keys(o).sort()` is used to determine the higher ranking hand.

**Snippet:**

```js
f=

s=>t=>(v=s=>(o={},l=n=0,z=3.5,[...s].sort().map(c=>(n+=o[c]=-~o[c],z*=!l|l+1==(l=c.charCodeAt()))),[n+z,Object.keys(o).sort((a,b)=>o[b]-o[a]||(o[b]>o[a]?1:-1))]),w=v(s),x=v(t),w[0]>x[0]||w[0]==x[0]&&w[1]<x[1]?s:t)

console.log(/voviu/.test(f('voviu')('kjsdf')))       //because a pair beats nothing 
console.log(/opoqo/.test(f('opoqo')('upper')))       //because 3 of a kind beats a pair
console.log(/ggegg/.test(f('woooo')('ggegg')))       //because 4 Gs beats 4 Os
console.log(/queue/.test(f('queue')('hopup')))       //because 2 pairs beats 1 pair
console.log(/ddkop/.test(f('lodpl')('ddkop')))       //because pair DD beats pair LL
console.log(/huhyg/.test(f('huhyg')('hijht')))       //both have pair HH, but G beats I
console.log(/ccyyz/.test(f('ddffh')('ccyyz')))       //both have 2 pairs, but CC(yyz) beats DD(ffh)
console.log(/nkunk/.test(f('okaok')('nkunk')))       //KK ties with KK, but NN beats OO
console.log(/bcdef/.test(f('abcdf')('bcdef')))       //because it is a straight
console.log(/qtery|retyq/.test(f('qtery')('retyq'))) //identical! so doesnt matter
console.log(/abedc/.test(f('abedc')('vyxwz')))       //because it is a "higher" straight
console.log(/hijkl/.test(f('hhhij')('hijkl')))       //because straight beats 3 of a kind
console.log(/zzzzz/.test(f('aaabb')('zzzzz')))       //because nothing beats 5 of a kind
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>28 27 29</s>  27 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

+2 & then -2 fix a bug, then re-golf.

```
FI=1ȦḤW
OµNĠLÞṚịµL€+Ç,N
ÇÞṪ
```

A monadic link taking a list of "hands" and returning (one of) the winners.

Works for all-uppercase OR all-lowercase input.
(...but not mixed, for that prepend the final line with `Œl` or `Œu`).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@/maWt4YtnDHUvCufz9jizwOTzv4c5ZD3d3@x/a6vOoaY324XYdP67D7SDhVf///49WyijNqExX0lHKyMzKKFGKBQA)** or see the [test suite](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#Lc6xTsMwEAbgvY9hseGlD4DEhIRatSNCUYYkduzGUc8JcYo7IZYMvEElEAPqUHVFAtGpAYnXSF8kXGxuudOnX3fXX11fjH@33cfbzWg@@36dti/d56b7epof36enx/1529DZqG0G3vVtg/RzuMywnR6e6dkEh9u@DwJSQ70whBKV3bGUhDQgoKEAFKM1L52sAAtFCC6Ek8Jww1EkaKOd5MB0jsKYAi/SSCuGzCKTlRPG0lSiJIm1a39LRaBQlsoslZMoTvAPSrBx/09R8dKilLyyxX@GswSltvcrv0dKmSl/S@U@E0VxjLIeioThHw).

#### How?

```
FI=1ȦḤW - Link 1, straight offset: grouped and reverse sorted hand ordinals
        -                     e.g. [[-101],[-100],[-99],[-98],[-97]]
F       - flatten                  [-101,-100,-99,-98,-97]
 I      - increments               [1,1,1,1]
  =1    - equal 1? (vectorises)    [1,1,1,1]
    Ȧ   - any and all?             1
     Ḥ  - double                   2
      W - wrap in a list           [2]
        -   The purpose of this is so that when "a" from Link 2 represents a straight we
        -   get [2], whereas for any other hand we get [0]. Adding the [2] to [1,1,1,1,1]
        -   (the lengths of a straight's groups) yields [3,1,1,1,1], placing it between
        -   three of a kind, [3,1,1], and a full house, [3,2], as required.

OµNĠLÞṚịµL€+Ç,N - Link 2, hand rank key function: list of characters       e.g. "huhyg"
O               - cast to ordinals                                [104,117,104,121,103]
 µ              - monadic chain separation, call that o
  N             - negate (to give them a reverse-sort order) [-104,-117,-104,-121,-103]
   Ġ            - group indices by value                            [[4],[2],[1,3],[5]]
     Þ          - sort by key function:
    L           -   length                                          [[4],[2],[5],[1,3]]
      Ṛ         - reverse                                           [[1,3],[5],[2],[4]]
       ị        - index into o                       [[-104,-104],[-103],[-117],[-121]]
        µ       - monadic chain separation (call that a)
         L€     - length of €ach                                              [2,1,1,1]
            Ç   - call last link (2) as a monad -> [isStraight? * 2]                [0]
           +    - addition (vectorises)                                       [2,1,1,1]
              N - negate o                                [[104,104],[103],[117],[121]]
             ,  - pair                        [[2,1,1,1],[[104,104],[103],[117],[121]]]
                -   now sorting by this will first be comparing the hand class, and if
                -   and only if they match comparing the card values in the required order.

ÇÞḢ - Main link: list of lists of characters (list of hands)
 Þ  - sort by key function:
Ç   -   last link (2) as a monad
  Ṫ - tail (best or an equal-best hand)
```

Comment: So freaking short compared to what I'm making in JS 0.o

Comment: @StephenS Welcome to PPCG, where you make something in some non-golfing language and then someone makes something in Jelly, 05AB1E, Pyth, CJam, etc that's shorter than your language name :I :P

Comment: @StephenS - JS should compete with JS. Do not let golfing languages deter you from submitting well thought out solutions in other languages!

Comment: @JonathanAllan it deters me from putting too much effort into overthinking and abstracting a problem that can be solved in ~25 characters, [here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m44Ljz01/) I was working on - I wrote all the boilerplate and none of the actual code

Comment: This is awesome, but I recently added a test case that this doesn't compute, specifically ["hhhij","hijkl"]. I think it's because of the way you rank a straight as [3,1,1,1,1]?

Comment: @Octopus Ah, well it was comparing flat lists due to the concatenate and hence erroring when comparing a string with an int (oops) but you were still right about the sort order too. I might be able to change it to save bytes again... but it is fixed for now.

Comment: @Octopus - indeed I could, back to 27 bytes again.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (<strike>250</strike> <strike>247</strike> 232 bytes)

```
S=d=>(x={},l=99,h=s=0,[...d].map(v=>x[v]=-~x[v]),Object.keys(x).map(v=>(c=91-v.charCodeAt(),t=x[v],s+=1e4**t,c<x[t]?0:x[t]=c,g=(h=c>h?c:h)-(l=c<l?c:l))),[5,4,3,2,1].map(v=>s+=0|x[v]**v),s+(s<5e7&&g<5?1e13:0)),C=a=>b=>(S(a)>S(b)?a:b)
```

#### Ungolfed code & test cases in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CookieJon/8yq8ow1b/

Saved some bytes with thanks to @RickHitchcock. @StephenS & @Arnauld

Comment: This is what I was trying to make but had no clue how to make.

Comment: Nor did I until after I started! :-)

Comment: `s=0,h=0` => `s=h=0` I believe

Comment: Fixed now after much hair-pulling.  Determining the tie-breaker in cases where the hand is the same AND the lowest characters in the 1st & 2nd largest groups were the same was the killer (33 bytes or so JUST for that!?) :-(

Comment: `x[v]=x[v]?++x[v]:1` can become `x[v]=(x[v]|0)+1`, saving 3 bytes.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Handy, thanks!

Comment: Since you're not calling `C` except when you run it, you don't need the `C=`. You can also save some bytes with currying - `=(a,b)=>` => `=>a=>b`, switch all of your calls from `C(a,b)` to `C(a)(b)` [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8yq8ow1b/20/) (not completely fixed)

Comment: We took very different approaches, and dealing with ties was definitely the difficult part of this challenge.  I think I just now understand how you do that.  Clever!

Comment: I think `x[v]=-~x[v]` should work as well.

Comment: @RickHitchcock ...not as clever as sorting - which never once occurred to me. :P  Well done.

Comment: There's a new test case that doesn't seem to work with your code: `=C('OKAOK')('NKUNK')` returns **OKAOK**. I've been struggling to come up with a scoring function that works without doing a string comparison after sorting the keys, so I don't think this will be an easy fix.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Ha, of course it doesn't! :-(  I'll have a think and update it later, thanks.

Comment: @RickHitchcock or mods, I don't have time to fix for that test case.. what's the etiquette... delete this answer indefinitely, or just leave it as an example bar that test case?

Comment: Your code worked for the initial test cases, and it's possible that it could be modified to work for all cases.  I think you earned your points, so I'd say leave it.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.7, <s>242</s> 223 bytes

```
from collections import*
s=sorted
f=lambda x,y:s(map(lambda h:(lambda (r,n):((3,1.5)if len(r)==5 and ord(r[0])+4==ord(r[4])else n,[-ord(d) for d in r],h))(zip(*s(Counter(h).items(),key=lambda z:(-z[1],z[0])))),(x,y)))[1][2]
```

Similar in basic concept to the javascript examples (sort by hand strength with an exception for straights; then by rank); but taking advantage of `collections.Counter` Unfortunately, `.most_common` doesn't have quite the desired behavior; so had to add a custom sort key.

Edit: a bit more code golfing to trim down 19 bytes.

**Un-golfed code**

```
from collections import Counter

def convertHand(h):
    # first get item counts, appropriately ordered; e.g. cbabc -> (('b',2), ('c',2),('a',1))
    sortedPairs = sorted(Counter(h).items(),key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0]))
    
    # 'unzip' the tuples to get (('b','c','a'), (2,2,1))
    ranks, numberFound = zip(*sortedPairs) 

    if len(ranks)==5:
        # no pairs; is it a straight? well, since they are in increasing order...
        if ord(ranks[0])+4 == ord(ranks[4]):
            # replace numberFound with something that will sort above 3 of a kind but below full house
            numberFound = (3,1.5)

    # invert the values of the ranks, so they are in decreasing, rather then increasing order
    ranks = [-ord(r) for r in ranks]

    # arrange tuples so we can sort by numberFound, and then ranks; and keep a reference to the hand
    return (numberFound, ranks, h)
            
# put it all together...
def f(x,y):
    hands = [convertHand(h) for h in (x,y)]
    rankedHands = sorted(hands)
    return rankedHands[1][2]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 635 bytes

```
H[x_]:=Block[{t},T=Sort@ToCharacterCode[x];L=Last/@Tally@T;t=0;S=Count;If[S[L,2]==1,t=1];If[S[L,2]==2,t=2];If[S[L,3]==1,t=3];If[S[Differences@T,1]==4,t=4];If[S[L,2]==1&&S[L,3]==1,t=5];If[S[L,4]==1,t=6];If[S[L,5]==1,t=7];t];F[K_,v_]:=First@Flatten@Cases[Tally@K,{_,v}];B=ToCharacterCode;(Z=Sort@B@#1;Y=Sort@B@#2;a=H[#1];b=H[#2];If[a>b,P@#1,If[a<b,P@#2]]If[a==b&&a==0,If[Z[[1]]<Y[[1]],P@#1,P@#2]];If[a==b&&(a==1||a==2),If[F[Z,2]<F[Y,2],P@#1,If[F[Z,2]==F[Y,2],If[F[Z,1]<F[Y,1],P@#1,P@#2],P@#2]]];If[a==b&&(a==3||a==5),If[F[Z,3]<F[Y,3],P@#1,P@#2]];If[a==b&&a==6,If[F[Z,4]<F[Y,4],P@#1,P@#2]];If[a==b&&(a==7||a==4),If[Tr@Z<Tr@Y,P@#1,P@#2]])&
```

.
.
**Input form**

> ["abcde", "kkekk"]

Comment: Is there a way to test this online?

Comment: https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/     paste with ctrl+v add the input at the end of the code and run with shift+enter